# Network first caching of index.html using workbox.js

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, workbox

I've integrated a service worker into our Single Page App built with ReactJS, using the workbox-build package by Google.

I'm having some troubles on the pre-caching of the index.html, specifically the service worker is serving an outdated index.html everytime we release a new build. Since it served an outdated index.html, the main JavaScript file is not found since it is versioned based on the build.

```
</div><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.fa34a3ce.js"></script>
```

I have also tried to remove the index.html from pre-cache, and have it in the runtime cache with a network first setting. But it doesn't seem to be cached by the service worker.

```
runtimeCaching: [
  {
    urlPattern: /\/$/,
    handler: 'networkFirst',
    options: {
      cacheName: 'my-cache-index'
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You may give a shot at this: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin. It creates the index.html from template at each build.

Comment: Hi @AliAnkarali, appreciate the response. I forgot to say that we are using create-react-app and wouldn't want to lean into eject-ing if possible.

Comment: You are most likely running into a common double caching situation, refer to this: [Cache Control](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/service-worker-checklist#cache-control_of_your_service_worker_file) and upcoming changes in Chrome [Fresher Service Workers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/fresher-sw)

Comment: @DeanTaylor, this is as you have said. I was able to explore this up to the NGINX config that was serving our service-worker.js file, and upon adding the Cache-Control header into a specific the location block in our NGINX config, I was able to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @user3477119 I've posted by comment as an answer feel free to mark it as the answer.

Comment: How did you exclude `index.html` from precache (considering you are using create-react-app or just workbox webpack plugin)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely running into a common double caching situation, refer to this [Cache Control](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/service-worker-checklist#cache-control_of_your_service_worker_file) and upcoming changes in Chrome [Fresher Service Workers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/fresher-sw).

Answer (score 0):

I [tried very hard](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1767#issuecomment-553695250) to setup the network first strategy for precaching but I failed. I've gave up trying and implemented the following strategy: *cache first but apply the update on a simple page reload*.

To implement it, just add the following option to your Workbox service worker builder (e.g. the Webpack plugin):

```
skipWaiting: true
```

Or, if you write the service worker by yourself, add the line to your service worker code:

```js
workbox.core.skipWaiting();
```

Furthermore, you can show an alert to the user when your application has been updated, and/or reload the page automatically:

```js
// Your service worker registration code
// ...

const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl);

registration.onupdatefound = () => {
  const installingWorker = registration.installing;
  if (installingWorker == null) {
    return;
  }
  installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
    if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
      if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
        if (confirm('App\'s been updated. Restart to apply the update?')) {
          location.reload();
        }
      } else {
        // The service worker has been installed for the first time
      }
    }
  };
};
```

By default, the update is checked when the code above is run. You can trigger a check for update manually by calling:

```
// An appendix to the previous code block
registration.update();
```

Unfortunately, there is [no straightforward way to find out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45759595/1118709) that there is no update.